# How to perform MINUS operation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I'm trying to create a MINUS query like Mysql (DATASET1-DATASET2) in elasticsearch using queryDSL but can't find a way.

Anyone could show me the way?
Tx in advance

Comment: maybe you can accomplish this operation by [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: Hi @M_M if the answer has solved your question please consider accepting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. But there is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bool query with must and must not.
[Documentation on the bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

You would put the query for DATASET1 in the must and the query for DATASET2 in must_not:

```
{
"bool" : {
    "must" : {
        DATASET1
    }
    "must_not" : {
        DATASET2
    }
}
```

}

For example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "range": {
              "@timestamp": {
                "lte": 1467811620000,
                "gte": 1467811520000
              }
            }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "_type": "bus-api"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would return all the documents between those two times, excluding those of type `bus-api`.